# Greater than comparison gives inconsistent results in Bash

Tags: bash, string-comparison

This script seems to give inconsistent results. For example, when the `if` statement sees its first string that is greater, it works fine. But, sometimes, later strings that are larger get ignored completely:

```
ITEM[0]="XX"
ITEM[1]="XXXXXXX"
ITEM[2]="X"
ITEM[3]="XXXXXXXXXXXX"
ITEM[4]="XXXX"

SETPOINT=0
for i in "${!ITEM[@]}"; do
        STRING="${ITEM[$i]}"
        LENGTH=${#STRING}
        echo "String length = $LENGTH"
        if [ $LENGTH \> $SETPOINT ]; then
                SETPOINT=$LENGTH
                echo "Setpoint was updated to $SETPOINT"
        fi
        echo "Loop again"
done
echo "Final setpoint = $SETPOINT"
```

Here is the example output:

```
String length = 2
Setpoint was updated to 2
Loop again

String length = 7
Setpoint was updated to 7
Loop again

String length = 1
Loop again

String length = 12 <--- Why didn't it catch this one?????
Loop again

String length = 4
Loop again

Final setpoint = 7
```

Also, originally I had tried to do the variable expansion and string counting inside the `if` statement, so I didn't have to create "STRING" and "LENGTH", but I could not figure out the syntax to both expand the array variable and count the string at same time inside the `if`. So, if you have a thought on that too in order to shorten the code, that would be amazing!

Thanks!

Comment: From an interactive bash prompt, type `help [` then type `help test` -- the `>` operator does *string* comparison, which compares according to lexical (dictionary) order. There are different operators that do arithmetic comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `\>` with `-gt`.

`man test` explains that:

```
 s1 > s2       True if string s1 comes after s2 based on the binary value of their characters.
 n1 -gt n2     True if the integer n1 is algebraically greater than the integer n2.
```